# Putting images over flexbox?

Tags: html

I'm trying to put these circle images over my flexboxes like this picture:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XqxK.png)

I can't get the images to move up, I tried adding margin-bottom and the images stay stuck inside of the flexboxes. This is what mine currently looks like: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlnCM.png)

If anyone could help me, I'd gladly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

```css
.contact-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.boxes, logos {
    width: 22.92vw;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 1.18vw;
    margin: 2.52vw;
    text-align: center;
}

.logos {
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.info {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.26vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-flex">
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="logos">
            <img src="Contacts/phone-01.png" width="80px">
        </div>
    <div class="info">
    <br><p><b>Call Us</b><br><br>
        Te: <b>519-725-7625</b></p>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="logos">
        <img src="Contacts/clock-01.png" width="80px">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
    <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <td>10am - 6pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <td>10am - 6pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <td>10am - 6pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <td>10am - 8pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <td>10am - 8pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <td>10am - 6pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sunday</th>
    <td>12pm - 5pm</td>
  </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="logos">
        <img src="Contacts/location-01.png" width="80px">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
       <p><br>The Shops<br>
        At Waterloo Town Square<br>
        75 King St. S,<br>
        Waterloo, Ontario, Canada</p> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css .logos definition you need to correct:

```
.logos {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Where margin top is negative of (your image height size)/2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```css
.contact-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:300px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-top:20px;
}

.boxes, logos {
    width: 22.92vw;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 1.18vw;
    margin: 2.52vw;
    text-align: center;
}

.logos {
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.info {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.26vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-flex">
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="logos">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" style="border-radius:50%;">
        </div>
    <div class="info">
    <br><p><b>Call Us</b><br><br>
        Te: <b>519-725-7625</b></p>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="logos">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" style="border-radius:50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
    <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <td>10am - 6pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <td>10am - 6pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <td>10am - 6pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <td>10am - 8pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <td>10am - 8pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <td>10am - 6pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sunday</th>
    <td>12pm - 5pm</td>
  </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="logos">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" style="border-radius:50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
       <p><br>The Shops<br>
        At Waterloo Town Square<br>
        75 King St. S,<br>
        Waterloo, Ontario, Canada</p> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Margin-top to the .logos class and padding to the .boxes, logos class so that the text does not sit to close to the bottom edge of the Boxes.

```
.logos {
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    margin-top:-45px;
}

.boxes, logos {
    width: 22.92vw;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 1.18vw;
    margin: 2.52vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's at least 3 ways to do this depending on what side effects you want.

Change

```
.logos {
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

to

A) as pointed out by others:

```
.logos {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

a negative `margin-top` will pull it, and bring the content below it up as well.

B)

```
.logos {
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

This will pull your circles up, but leave the the original space they occupied untouched

C)

```
.logos {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-20px;
}

.boxes, logos {
    ...
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Same side effects as A, but with more code.